# Loop through columns looping through rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a script that loops through columns and set variables from rows 2, 3 and 4. I've found the following example script and tried to rewrite it to loop through columns but when I replace "row" with "column" it still loops through rows.

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the loop occurs in the array of arrays you get with `getValues()` in which each rows content is represented by an array of column values.

To iterate on a row just use `data[0]` and loop into it.(`data[0][0]`, `data[0][1]`, `data[0][n]`...)

Values from other rows will be in `data[1][n]`, `data[2][n]` etc., n being the loop index

Note also that you selected a range made of 2 rows and you mention in your question that you need data from 2,3 and 4... so adjust the range to necessary size.

**Code example**:

```js
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (n in data[0]) {
  var emailAddress = data[0][n];  // First row in each column
  var message = data[1][n];       // Second row in each column
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: This is crystal clear!