# Loop over multiple rows in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am stuck, the simple yet dreaded for loop is my nemesis and I could use some help.  I have a google sheet that has at present 3 rows (not including headers) & 8 columns. the number of rows will grow dynamically as users provide input via a web app.  I need to take the data collected in this sheet and use it to direct an email to a particular service within our organisation.

I don't need all 8 columns of data in fact I only need 6.  What I'm struggling with is iterating across all the columns and rows.  I have tried a simple for loop, a nested for loop and a for each function, none of which produce the output I expect :(

My most up to date code is below:

```
function serviceSelector() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Response');
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var holderArray = [];
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     holderArray.push(
       data[1][0],
       data[1][1],
       data[1][2],
       data[1][4],
       data[1][5],
       data[1][6]);
  }
 Logger.log(holderArray);


//  switch(holderArray[1]){
//    case 'Volunteering':
//      MailApp.sendEmail('andypaulstevens@gmail.com', 'Message ID# ' +holderArray[2], 'You have receive the following message regarding Volunteering: \n\n'+holderArray[3]); 
//      break;  
//    case 'Home Help Service':
//      MailApp.sendEmail('andypaulstevens@gmail.com', 'Message ID# ' +holderArray[2], 'You have receive the following message regarding the Home Help Service: \n\n'+holderArray[3]); 
//      break;
//  }
}
```

I have commented out the switch statement to resolve the issue with getting the right data.

Following the GREAT advice provided already I have updated my code as follows:

```
function serviceSelector() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Response');
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow() -1,8);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var holderArray = [];
  for(i in data[0]){
    for(j in data[i]){
      holderArray.push(data[j])
    }
  }

  Logger.log(holderArray);
```

The log output is as follows:

[20-03-26 12:35:22:136 GMT] [[Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:43:38 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k4rp4, Home Help Service, Hello World, andy.s@.uk], [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:44:40 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k63ae, Home Help Service, Hello World, andy.s@.uk], [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:46:38 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k8mmo, Home Help Service, Hi Joolz, Just sending a quick email to show you how the web form would function. I'm getting there with it, just need the email addresses and to figure out how to trigger it when we get a response. Other than that it's almost complete :), andy.s@.uk], null, null, null, null, null, [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:43:38 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k4rp4, Home Help Service, Hello World, andy.s@.uk], [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:44:40 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k63ae, Home Help Service, Hello World, andy.s@.uk], [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:46:38 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k8mmo, Home Help Service, Hi Joolz, Just sending a quick email to show you how the web form would function. I'm getting there with it, just need the email addresses and to figure out how to trigger it when we get a response. Other than that it's almost complete :), andy.s@.uk], null, null, null, null, null, [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:43:38 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k4rp4, Home Help Service, Hello World, andy.s@.uk], [Andy, Stevens, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:44:40 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k63ae, Home Help Service, Hello World, andy.s@org.uk], [Andy, S, andys@.com, Wed Mar 25 2020 16:46:38 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), k87k8mmo, Home Help Service, Hi Joolz, Just sending a quick email to show you how the web form would function. I'm getting there with it, just need the email addresses and to figure out how to trigger it when we get a response. Other than that it's almost complete :), andy.s@.uk], null, null, null, null, null]

Complete code added below, including the switch statement where am I going wrong?

```
function serviceSelector() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Response');
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow() -1,8);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var cols = range.getNumColumns();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var holderArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
       holderArray.push(data[i][j]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(holderArray);
  Logger.log(holderArray);
  switch(holderArray[5]){
    case 'Volunteering':
      MailApp.sendEmail(holderArray[2], 'Message ID# ' +holderArray[4], 'You have receive the following message regarding Volunteering: \n\n'+holderArray [6]); 
      break;  
    case 'Home Help Service':
      MailApp.sendEmail(holderArray[2], 'Message ID# ' +holderArray[4], 'You have receive the following message regarding the Home Help Service: \n\n'+holderArray [6]); 
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share what you see in console after doing `Logger.log(holderArray);`

Comment: Please share how the ```data``` looks like and what the output you want to achieve.

Comment: And what is the result you expect? What is the result you got?

Comment: You are looping with  the variable `i` - so far so good. But when you push the data into your array you hard-code the array address `data[1][0]`. The idea here is that `i` should substitute for one of those values  - such as `data[1][i],` Also, you need two loops, one for the columns and one for the rows - [Loop through columns looping through rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24937332/1330560) has a good example.

Comment: Skip the holder array. Move the switch inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

The `data` variable you have is a *two-dimensional array* which essentially means that in order to traverse it, you will be needing two `for` loops in this case. Since the `data` might not have the same number of rows and columns, you could add two variables which will represent the `numbers of rows` and `columns` you have. In this way, one loop will traverse the rows and the other one will traverse the columns. Therefore, each traversal is represented by the `data[i][j]` element.

#### Snippet

```
 var cols = range.getNumColumns();
 var rows = range.getNumRows();
 var holderArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
       holderArray.push(data[i][j]);
```

If you only need `6` columns you can easily replace the `cols` variable with `6`.

#### Reference

- [Range Class Apps Script - getNumColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows);
- [JavaScript For Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I had already tried this and it doesn't work.  I have three rows of data:


row1
row2
row3

Each time I run the code it loops over the first row only?

Comment: Hello @APStevens, did you use the appropriate variables? The code that I have provided works fine for me and I can retrieve the data from my Spreadsheet and store it in another array. Are you sure you don't have any typos in your code? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, I can't see any typos :( it iterates through the columns ok but it doesn't iterate through the rows. Each time I run the code I get sent an email relating to the first row, even though there are two further rows beneath it, I want it to pick up the last row.  So that when I add my onSubmit trigger when a new entry is added to the sheet it will send an email to the relevant department.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hello @ApStevens, I suggest you keep the `var range = sheet.getDataRange();` just like you declared it at first. If you want to skip the first row, just simply start the first `for` loop from `var i=1` instead of `var i=0`. Cheers!